# write a function to subset df based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, function, conditional-statements, subset

This is an example of my data: Original data has 20 cols and 1350 rows.

```
 a <- c("blue", "red", "green", "blue","cyan")
 b <- c("red","red","green","blue", "orange")
 data <- data.frame(a,b)
```

Following code is the code that works well. in this code, I purposed
1. subset df based on the conditions below
2. removed unused levels 
3. and then result will turn in table with 2 by 2 dimenstion

```
 blue.red <- subset(data, col1 %in% c("blue", "red") & 
               col2 %in% c("blue", "red"))
 rem <- droplevels(blue.red)
 table(rem$col1, rem.col2)
```

Here I tried to write a function to achieve the same purpose as the code above.

```
 sub_fun <- function(data, i, j...){
   subs <-subset(data, col1 %in% c("i", "j") &
             col2 %in% c("i", "j"))
   rem <- droplevels(subs)
   return(table(rem$i, rem$j))
 }

 check <- sub_fun(data, "blue", "red")
 check1 <-sub_fun(data, "red", "green"
```

But output tablea are empty. How should I write a function 
to subset this data?

Comment: On _Stack Overflow_ it's strongly recommended that you provide `dput(data)`.

Comment: Is the `...` in `sub_fun` a typo or meant to be `function(data, i, j, ...) {` ? If the latter, you don't seem to need it in your function.

Comment: hi? I tried with and without this sign. But the result is still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the inverted commas around `i` and `j` in your function body, otherwise it will keep only observation containing `"i"` or `"j"` in `col1` and `col2`:

```
sub_fun <- function(data, i, j){
  subs <- subset(data, col1 %in% c(i, j) & col2 %in% c(i, j))
  rem <- droplevels(subs)
  # if you assume that only columns col1 & col2 are in data
  return(table(rem))
  # if you have more columns in data then:
  # return(table(rem[, c('col1', 'col2')]))
}
```

that should do the trick

edit: the error you are getting is due to the fact that you were trying to extract `i` and `j` from `rem`, where `i = 'blue'` and `j = 'red'` (it does not make sense since `i` and `j` are not colnames of `rem`).

Comment: Some clarity for non-British-English-speaking folks: *inverted commas* are called *quotation marks* on our side of the pond

Comment: tried without " ". But it says " Error in sp.tree %in% c(i, j) : object 'j' not found"

Comment: @SunRise I just updated the answer, there was an error as outlined by markus in a comment

Comment: I apply the code to my data in this way: check <- sub_fun(data, "col1", "col2"). Also there is an error  "Error in table(rem) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements"

Comment: @SunRise that's wrong. your `i` and `j` input in `sub_fun()` corresponds to observations in `col1` and `col2` from `data`, hence you can't call `sub_fun` with `i = "col1", j = "col2"`. it won't be able to locate entries in `data` that are either `"col1"` or `"col2"`. take a look at the update function in the response

Comment: oookey! that is right, now it works well. Thank you so so much!